# How to scale or resize a long equation in LYX without using Latex Code?

Tags: equations, lyx

I am completely new to Latex and I am using LYX editor. I am looking for a way to scale a long equation in LYX without using Latex code?? I have found similar questions but all the answers were given as Latex code snippet which I dont know how to use or insert in LYX editor.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello Chris, I dont know how to use the latex codes given as solutions in that link. I am looking for a way without using those codes. If you could let me know how to use such codes in LYX editor that would be a great help.

Comment: Why are you not interested in using LaTeX code?

Comment: Hello Werner, since I am new to Latex, I dont know how to insert that code in Lyx. I am inserting a Latex code block (LYX > Insert > Latex Code) in LYX and copying the same code given in some answers but it is not working and I dont know how to debug it. SO I am looking for some Manual ways.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84031/making-an-edit-to-an-inline-equation-that-went-off-of-the-screen and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91560/using-breqn-in-unnumbered-equation-in-lyx

Comment: If you have a problem getting something to work, post the .lyx file showing your problem. See here for more info: http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample